# Cisco PIX 515 ipv6

Tags: ipv6, cisco-pix

I know cisco pix 515 is an old and EOL device, but does anyone know if it supports IPv6 or is that completely out of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the pix 515 can handle IPv6 from version 7. Just don't expect any performance from it, because all IPv6 processing will be done in software, not in hardware.

Comment: Fortunately I don't really need any performance to speak of..
THere's only 15 computers behind it, whereof not more than 7 is online at the same time, and there's rarely much traffic to shovel around..

Ofcourse, the more performance the better, but in this case I don't think it will be that much noticable..

Answer (score 0):

At that scale, there's no excuse not to purchase an in-support, IPv6-capable Cisco ASA 5505 50-user firewall bundle (*ASA5505-50-BUN-K9*) for $500 US.

I have a couple of Pix 515e units running ASA 7.x software, and they're missing some key features. A real ASA, even the lowest-end variant, is still a step up.

Comment: Personally, i would agree, but my boss would not.
He didnt even want to buy this one, he wanted to keep running a dlink soho device with "firewall capabilities", which i did not think was appropriate, so i bought this one and donated it.

Theres a difference between donating $100 and $500.:)

I am working for a communal service company, not privately owned, so budgeting with tax money, i can in part understand him.

I much rather deal with older proffessional hardware than unreliable crap.:)

Comment: That's fair. Get to the newest ASA software version you can on the Pix and it'll certainly keep running. I have a 9-year-old unit still chugging away.